# Excel VBA-Duplicates run with button/add location

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel VBA and I really need your help. I have a code that will look for the duplicate values in Column A. This code will highlight the duplicate values. I want:

1.) This code to ONLY run when I click on a button.

2.) I would like to have (somewhere in the same worksheet), the number of duplicate results and a hyper link that when you click on it will direct you the duplicate result (this is because I have sometimes huge files that I need to validate). Here is the code I currently have:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim C As Range, i As Long
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.[A:A]) Is Nothing Then
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 For Each C In Target
   If C.Column = 1 And C.Value > "" Then
      If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Me.[A:A], C.Value) > 1 Then
         i = C.Interior.ColorIndex
         f = C.Font.ColorIndex
         C.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' Red
         C.Font.ColorIndex = 6 ' Yellow
          C.Select
          MsgBox "Duplicate Entry !", vbCritical, "Error"
         C.Interior.ColorIndex = i
         C.Font.ColorIndex = f
      End If
   End If
 Next
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 End If
 End Sub
```

I would really appreciate it if you help me with this.

Comment: Try adding a button to your worksheet... First take your code out of the `Worksheet_Change` event and create a module with a `Public Sub MyButton()`. Next, from the Developer tab, add a button to your worksheet (anywhere will do) and you'll be prompted to connect the button to a macro. Once you connect it, you should be set.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It does not work. Maybe I not modifying the code properly. I have other buttons and other codes in the same sheet, is this why?

Comment: If you're following the suggestion in the comment from @PeterT you also need to explicitly set Target to `A:A` and take out the `Intersect` test.

Comment: Thank you @Comintern, I tried it and it does not work for me. Like I said I am new in this, maybe I am not doing the modifications accordingly as you guys say :s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code to Module1 <kbd>**Alt**</kbd>+<kbd>**F11**</kbd>

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyButton()
    Dim RangeCell As Range, _
    MyData As Range
    Dim MyDupList As String
    Dim intMyCounter As Integer
    Dim MyUniqueList As Object
    Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngLoopRow As Long
    Dim lngWriteRow As Long

    Set MyData = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set MyUniqueList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MyDupList = "": intMyCounter = 0
    '// Find Duplicate
    For Each RangeCell In MyData
        If RangeCell <> "V" And RangeCell <> "R" Then
            If Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & MyData.Address & "," & RangeCell.Address & ")") > 1 Then
                '// Color. Change to suit RGB(141, 180, 226).
                RangeCell.Interior.Color = RGB(141, 255, 226)
                If MyUniqueList.exists(CStr(RangeCell)) = False Then
                    intMyCounter = intMyCounter + 1
                    MyUniqueList.Add CStr(RangeCell), intMyCounter
                    If MyDupList = "" Then
                        MyDupList = RangeCell
                    Else
                        MyDupList = MyDupList & vbNewLine & RangeCell
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                RangeCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If
        End If
    Next RangeCell
    '// Move duplicate from Column 1 to Column 7 = (G:G)
    lngWriteRow = 1
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For lngLoopRow = lngLastRow To 1 Step -1
        With Cells(lngLoopRow, 1)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & lngLastRow), .Value) > 1 Then
                If Range("G:G").Find(.Value, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                    Cells(lngWriteRow, 7) = .Value
                    lngWriteRow = lngWriteRow + 1
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next lngLoopRow

    Set MyData = Nothing: Set MyUniqueList = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If MyDupList <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Duplicate entries have been found:" & vbNewLine & MyDupList
    Else
        MsgBox "There were no duplicates found in " & MyData.Address
    End If
End Sub
```

.

```
Add Module
```

[image]

```
Add Button
```

[image]

```
Assign to Macro
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Omar, your code works. I just want to highlight duplicates in Column A only, not comparing two columns with duplicates. Do you know how can I solve my second problem?: 2.) I would like to have (somewhere in the same worksheet), the number of duplicate results and a hyper link that when you click on it will direct you the duplicate result (this is because I have sometimes huge files that I need to validate).