# Copying from one sheet to another using buttons based on value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using microsoft excel 2013.

So i have two sheets. "Cases" and "Summarize". All of my important info is on the Cases sheet. Is there way i can be on the "Summarize" sheet, push a button and copy all the cellrows with the value "RLH" from cases over to the summarize sheet?

I've filled the entire row up to N. And i want that entire row to be copied into the summarize sheet when I push the button. The "RLH" value is on the N(last) column.

I know how to create the button and how to insert the code. I've been googling my ass of, but I cant seem to find anything that fits me.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is very simple. that will get you started

assign to [Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063015/excel-vba-duplicates-run-with-button-add-location/)

```
Option Explicit
Sub Mybutton()
    '// declare a variable 
    Dim cRng As Range
    Dim rngA As Long
    Dim rngB As Long
    Dim Cols As Long
    Dim sCases As Worksheet
    Dim sSummarize As Worksheet

    '// Set the sheets name
    Set sCases = Sheets("Cases")
    Set sSummarize = Sheets("Summarize")

    '// goes through each cell in Sheets"Cases"
    '// and copes the Value "RLH" to Sheets"Summarize"
    '// it starts from last row in column A & looks up
    rngA = sCases.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    Cols = sCases.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    For Each cRng In sCases.Range("A2:A" & rngA)
        If cRng.Value = "RLH" Then '<<<<<<<<< Value = "RLT"
            rngB = sSummarize.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            sSummarize.Range("A" & rngB).Resize(1, Cols) = cRng.Resize(1, Cols).Value
        End If
    '// loop
    Next cRng

    Set sSummarize = Nothing
    Set sCases = Nothing
End Sub
```

hope this helps

you may also find help full on the following link  [MSDN Getting Started with VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Any pointers on how to only get out the rows with the value RLH, and how to copy them into an existing worksheet?

Comment: is that what your need?

Comment: Almost. If i somehow could tell VBA to only copy the cellrows with the value RLH over to the next sheet. Right now im gettin everything. But if possible i'd like to only copy the rows with RLH as the value in the N column

Comment: Holy shit. I just logged in some years later and noticed i forgot to answer you. Afaik the solution helped. Thank you @0m3r